# PSU noise and turning parts on

Tags: power-supply

When I unplug my PSU's cable and plug it again in the outlet, it starts making a high-pitched noise and starts trying to turn the PC parts on. The CPU cooler spins a bit, then shuts down again. The case LEDs are working.

To boot, I have to press the case button, then everything turns on fine. The PSU didn't do this before.

EDIT: Do I have to replace my PSU?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Do I have to switch my PSU?

Comment: By switch you mean replace?

Comment: Yes, I mean replace. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is still under warranty then send it in, and if not you could either fix it yourself if you have the knowledge and confidence or send it to a professional. If you don't want to do that then you could replace it. Also you could just live with the high pitch noise.

The high pitch noise could be coming from a capacitor or transformer but also could be that you are drawing too much current, or the outlet you are plugged into isn't providing enough amperage. You could do a simple test of trying on a different outlet and unplugging some components in your computer to see if that makes any difference.  If it does not then like I said you could either fix it, live with it, or replace it.